# Why does it say its the wrong code entered even though its the same as the key

Tags: python, random, key

I am trying to make a quest in python terminal but when i try to compare two code it says its wrong

```
import time
import random

def adventure():
   
    key = random.randint(111,999)

    delay = 1

    print()
    print("the code is", key)
    
    time.sleep(delay)

    uk = input("do you remember the code?")

    if uk == key:
        print("Good")

    else:
        print("wrong code")
```

Edit: so the solution was instead of

```
if uk == key:
```

do this

```
if int(uk) == key:
```

Comment: It is probably type issue, so you need to change the variable uk into int or change key to str before comparing them.
Also, try printing out the values next time. It will help you find bugs in your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

Answer (score 1):

A good explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

Essentially don't use 'is' to compare integers. Change your code at this point here and replace 'is' with '==' and it will work

```
if uk == key:
    print("Good")
```